# Thin question: how can I take out an old sign from my original .apk-file, is there any method?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, sign, apktool

*Hi there*,
My problem is: Google play is deleted my old app, to re-publish it I only need to raise its version, and I can do it with apktool by decoding it from .apk, but decoding is erasing my sign from application, I can re-sign it, but the problem is that I lost this original keystore long time ago. I need to re-publish it, without creating a new one in store. need help

***UPD:*** *Google send me this answer*, I see theres only way - creating a new app:

"I understand you're not able to use the original keystore for your app, com.Cold_Kitchen.Diving_Plane.

Unless you are enrolled in Google Play app signing, the only solution to this issue is to publish a new app with a new package name and a new key. In order to transition existing users to the new app, you’ll need to update the original app’s description with a link to the new app and unpublish the original app.

I absolutely understand this is a significant inconvenience, however, due to security concerns Google does not keep a copy of your keystore and at this time we do not support the deletion of apps or the re-use of package names."

Comment: you can't recover your lost keystore but you can replace keystore on playstore, you just need to enable google play app signing on play store console You can Replace new Keystore certification on play store.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  Google has had an option to do the signing for you for a few years.  If you had that option on, the keystore you signed with wasn't the actual keystore used, that was just a validation used to prove to google that it was yours.  In that case, you just need to contact google and they can reset the auth keystore.

If you didn't have that setting-  then they can reset your account to allow a new key, but none of your previous users will ever get an automatic update again-  they'd need to delete and reinstall to get new versions.

Comment: Google send me answer (in UPD to my question), I see that creating new app is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover your lost keystore but you can replace keystore on play store, you just need to enable google play app signing on play store console. You can replace new Keystore certification on play store. Then you can update your app, no need to Remove Your app from play Store. It’s Possible now, after May 2017 you can update your app if you lost your keystore or Keystore password. You can update your app using a new Keystore file please refer to this blog Keystore Lost in Android here I wrote how to update apk if you lost your Keystore follow these steps https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create and created new Keystore, I updated my app using these steps.

> **Lost or compromised upload key?**
>
> If you’ve lost your private upload key, or it’s been compromised, you
>   can create a new one, and then ask your account owner to contact
>   support to reset the key. When contacting support, make sure that your
>   account owner attaches the `upload_certificate.pem` file.
>
> After our support team registers the new upload key, you will receive
>   an email, and then you can update your `keystores` and register your
>   key with API providers.
>
> **Important**: Resetting your upload key doesn’t affect the app signing key that Google Play uses to re-sign APKs before delivering
>   them to users.

Next step :

**Report Here**

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs

Comment: To create google play sign I need to provide it my old keystore

Comment: You can Replace new Keystore certification on play store

Comment: Followed those steps, I created new jks-key, and exported its certificate in .pem format, but why, what next?

Comment: When I trying to upload encrypted_private_key to Console, to activate Google Signs for my app, it says that this key is different that the old key in my app

Comment: @MaxPaws please report here that you lost your old key  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs

Comment: I reported, attached my .pem file, but there was the same answer as before, the same mail, as in my "UPD" in question, that I must create new app and there is no other way.